# Angular JS create paragraphs by default if none are present

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am adding paragraphs from json file. How can I count them (I tried with .length) and if there are less than 10, I need to create default ones and add them on the page? For example user can add paragraphs with some custom text and if he adds 3 paragraphs I want to add 7 more by default. So all the time 10 are present on the page. Here is my structure and it is currently showing 4 paragraphs since I have only 4 in json file:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="p in list.paragraphs" ng-class="isSelectedBoard(p)">
     <p class="slide-wrap" ng-click="setMasterBoard(p)">
         some text goes here
     </p>
</div>
```

So, again if user don't add paragraph, I need to show 10 on the page with some default text and if user add 1 paragraph, he will have 1 custom paragraph and 9 default ones etc...

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Controller:

```
$scope.list = {};

$http.get('name.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    $scope.list = data;

});
```

Comment: Seems as though it would be much easier to do this in your controller.

Comment: ok, any suggestion? I mean working jsfiddle would be the best :-)

Comment: May I see your existing controller code or at least the portion that is relevant to the loading of these paragraphs?

Comment: check my edit for part of the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this in the controller. In your function that adds paragraphs from the json file, after adding all the paragraphs from the file, simply add enough default paragraphs to make the length of `paragraphs` equal to 10.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.list = {
    paragraphs: [{
      text: 'This is a user paragraph.',
      defaultBG: '#000'
    }, {
      text: 'This is another user paragraph.',
      defaultBG: '#000'
    }, {
      text: 'This is a third user paragraph.',
      defaultBG: '#000'
    }]
  }

  var defaultParagraph = {
    text: 'This is a default paragraph.',
    defaultBG: '#000'
  };

  for (var i = $scope.list.paragraphs.length; i < 10; i++) {
    $scope.list.paragraphs.push(defaultParagraph);
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="p in list.paragraphs track by $index" ng-class="isSelectedBoard(p)">
    <p class="slide-wrap" ng-click="setMasterBoard(p)">
      {{p.text}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There you go, here's your answer. This is essentially what I was driving at.

Comment: Thanks but I get `ng repeat dupes` error, what should I change in html to solve this?

Comment: When I add `track by $index` it shows the paragraphs but I still have that error showing

Comment: @Lex Also is it possible to pass additional data with that push? For example, if I add var defaultBG = "#000"; how can I pass this along with defaultParagraph?

Comment: @Morpheus You can make the paragraphs be objects that contain whatever properties you want. What do the user paragraphs look like? You can make the default one match those. As for the dupes error, I've used track by $index to fix that before, so I'm not sure. Let me look into it.

Comment: @Morpheus I updated my answer to be runnable (I create the user paragraphs in the code, instead of reading them from the json file, to simplify things). This demonstrates using `track by $index` to remove that dupes error, and structuring the paragraphs as objects. Hopefully this helps clear up your questions.

Comment: @forgivenson Hmmm... It is working but the I can't get rid of that error... Let me check something, if  I don't solve it, should I post it here?